# Common ways to tweak the .NET 4.5 GC for games and other real time applications?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, .net-4.5

I'm working on a game engine in C# and am running into situations where while doing some memory intensive operations, the garbage collection causes noticeable stutters once every multiple frames. What are common ways to tweak the garbage collector in .NET to avoid problems like this or to otherwise optimize it for real-time applications?

Comment: You're noticing full GC or Gen1 or Gen0? based on that you can apply many strategies to prevent GC. For example avoiding heap allocation by using structs etc.  You need to measure and understand the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with profiling. Find out what's giving you trouble and find a way to get rid of that. There's a few tweaks like using the multi-threaded GC, but that only really helps much for server applications with a few worker threads.

Your best bet is to make sure most of the memory you do release is still in generation 0 - those collections are usually fast enough not to introduce stutter in 60 FPS application.

And of course, just as in C++ or whatever else - limit your allocations and deallocations. You're probably doing lots of those that are completely unnecessary - again, profiling helps you pinpoint those very easily. If you're collecting every few frames, you're doing something very wrong.

Of course, C++ gives you a few more options to e.g. reuse memory. However, this is not insurmountable by far. The GC only handles heap allocations (and collections) - the stack is only used as one of the root references. So depending on your design, if you e.g. allocate new classes as local variables in your methods, it might be well worth it to replace those with `struct`s, which will tend to be allocated on the stack. There's no way to *force* this behaviour (outside of unsafe code - and you should always think 10 times before trying that :D), but the CLR does try to put anything that can be on the stack on the stack :)

Comment: The specific problem that's going on is a voxel map to mesh conversion function that's running every frame. I don't expect this to ever happen in real use of the game engine but it's used for a water effect in a demo. I've run the profiler over it and managed to solve major problems that were occurring with it, but don't see many other improvements I can make next to what I've already done.

Comment: @LaylConway Usually, you wouldn't recreate the mesh. That's where vertex buffers and similar come in handy - you can pre-allocate as many indices and vertices as you think you will need, and only fill the data as needed (those being structs, you can avoid millions of allocations) - and when it comes to rendering, render as many as there actually are, rather than the whole vertex/index buffer. The fact that VB/IBs have been with us long before practical .NET games nicely shows that you've got a similar performance issue with unmanaged code :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at re-using the arrays and VBOs for this purpose. Meanwhile a scan after some more optimizations has shown that most allocations now are actually being made by the multi dimensional array acessor and... the parts of the engine that warn me if too many allocations are happening.